# Can I make a generic CompiledQuery that accepts multiple tables and generic types?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I have multiple tables with an "id" component.  I'd like to use LINQ to get an item from one of these tables with the correct LINQ-To-SQL type, but only using one CompiledQuery.

Here's an example that works currently. Say the object type defined in the DBML is "myitem" and its table is "myitems".

```
    var getOneItem = CompiledQuery.Compile(
        (MyDataContext db, long id) => ((from i in db.myitems
                                              where i.id == id
                                              select i).SingleOrDefault()));
```

I'd like to make this, where the type can be "myitem", "myitems2", or whatever table and object type I might be interested in.

```
    var getOneItemAnyTable = CompiledQuery.Compile(
        (Table tab, Type T long id) => ((from anItem in tab<T>
                                              where anItem.id == id
                                              select anItem).SingleOrDefault()));
```

I made up this syntax because I'm not sure what the syntax should look like here.  Any ideas if it's possible?  Would I have to munge the DBML to make some kind of superclass for the types involved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't make the one compiled-query span multiple tables (if that is what you mean); how would it know where to look? EF supports something like this with inheritance (and multiple tables), but even with inheritance LINQ-to-SQL only supports **single-table** discriminated inheritance.

The heart of this question is largely identical [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439086/get-entity-from-table-using-reflection-from-abstract-type) from earlier today. The tricky bit is the primary key, since that is hard to define abstractly. The rest is just `GetTable<T>` (with LINQ-to-SQL at least).

You don't need a superclass in this case - just a way to get the primary key. Fortunately, I seem to recall that LINQ-to-SQL offers a way to do this (without needing to use the attributes, which is not a pre-req of LINQ-to-SQL); the following doesn't pre-compile (and is untested), but should be fairly close:

(**update** fixed and tested)

Usage first:

```
Foo foo = ctx.Get<Foo>(fooid);
Bar bar = ctx.Get<Bar>(barid);
```

code:

```
    public static TItem Get<TItem, TKey>(
        this DataContext ctx, TKey key)
        where TItem : class
    {
        var table = ctx.GetTable<TItem>();
        var primaryKey = ctx.Mapping.GetMetaType(typeof(TItem))
                .DataMembers.Where(
            member => member.IsPrimaryKey).Single().Member.Name;

        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem), "item");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.PropertyOrField(item, primaryKey),
                Expression.Constant(key, typeof(TKey))),
                item);
        return table.Single(lambda);
    }
    public static TItem Get<TItem>( // common case
        this DataContext ctx, int key)
        where TItem : class
    {
        return Get<TItem, int>(ctx, key);
    }
    public static TItem Get<TItem>( // common case
       this DataContext ctx, string key)
       where TItem : class
    {
        return Get<TItem, string>(ctx, key);
    }
```

I'll see if I can find a way to pre-compile it...

Comment: for my ignorance; what is single table discriminated inheritance that is supported by linq-to-sql.

Comment: (updated example, btw) - where the table has a column such as "CustType", and the object-type is determined by that column. Like so: http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/26/LINQToSQLInheritanceDiscriminatorColumnExampleInheritanceMappingTutorial.aspx

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if I missed anything but I've already developed an application by using multiple table inheritance without using discriminatior by kind of POCO.

Comment: To clarify; there was a base entity that includes base functionalities, and all other entities derived from that base one. By using that I made a generic method to get a single row from any entity.

Comment: Very interesting... Out of curiosity, are you using attributed meta-models, or external (xml) meta-models?

Comment: Manually created classes, or dbml-generated? I'm simply curious? (and I'm trying a few things too ;-p)

Comment: Ahhh... the dbml hates it, but that is neat.

Comment: Hmm, I pointed that I've used kind of POCO. I knew that in POCO you have to create your classes manually. But sure, dbml could hate it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing that, derive all your entities from a base entity that has common properties in your entities (like Id). Implementing these layer with POCO will help you.

Comment: Cheers for the info (in comments to my post); +1