# How do I reference a field in Linq based on a dynamic fieldname

Tags: c#, linq

Firstly, apologies for the bad question title - not entirely sure if I am asking the correct thing.

Normally I can do the following to access a field:

```
MyTables table = dc.MyTables.SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == someId);
somevalue = table.samplefield;
```

In this instance the variable *somevalue* would end up having the value of the field *samplefield*.

Now I have a scenario where I want to populate a variable, but I don't know the name of the table field at design time.  I do however, have this fieldname in a string.  Is it therefore possible to fetch a value using this string?

Hoping this makes sense!

Comment: Which do you know - "id", or "sampleField"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use reflection, like this: (Untested)

```
somevalue = typeof(MyTable).GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(table, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `string s = "sampleField";`, then you can just use reflection:

```
object value = table.GetType().GetProperty(s).GetValue(table, null);
```

If you need the PKID as a string, it is more complex, and you need to use a runtime-generated lambda. *Exactly* how depends slightly on the implementation - for example, to identify the PK from LINQ-to-SQL, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249525/determine-primary-key-using-linq-to-sql/1249690#1249690) which looks at the data-contexts metadata.

Answer (score 3):

Weirdly I have just been reading something similar on Scott Hanselman's blog, this is to set the where or ordering by a field name in a string but I think the select could be done in the same way. See:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode48DynamicQueryableMakesCustomLINQExpressionsEasier.aspx

The core being something like :

```
Dim Northwind As new NorthwindDataContext
Dim query = Northwind.Products
        .Where("CategoryID=2 And UnitPrice>3")
        .OrderBy("SupplierID")
GridView1.DataSource = query
GridView1.DataBind()
```

It may require some dynamic data references.

Comment: I like this solution better than reflection because it will work with IQueryables like Linq to SQL

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, you will need to use reflection.

```
public object GetField(object obj, string fieldName) { 
  var t = obj.GetType();
  var field = t.GetField(fieldName);
  return field.GetValue(obj);
}

somevalue = GetField(table, "someFieldName");
```

This works as long as the field is both instance and public.  You'd need to modify the GetField method call slightly if the accessibility was less than public.

Comment: Does LINQ to SQL really use fields and not properties?

Comment: @Slaks, no idea, but the OP said field inside of the question so I went with field.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely doable but does get alot more complicated. If you want to do a completely dynamic LINQ query you should check out these posts by Scott Hanselman.

- [The Weekly Code Sample 48 - DynamicQueryable makes custom LINQ expressions easier](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode48DynamicQueryableMakesCustomLINQExpressionsEasier.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed:+ScottHanselman+(Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com))
- [The Weekly Code Sample 47 - ASP.NET 3.5 Dynamic Data: FilterRepeaters and Dynamic Linq Query Generation](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode47ASPNET35DynamicDataFilterRepeatersAndDynamicLinqQueryGeneration.aspx)

Comment: After seeing all of the responses I definitely missed the boat. LINQ is not required for this scenario at all. The reflection methods shown here are exactly what you need.