# Linq query issues - determining column at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a linq question (linq to sql). I have the following peice of code which works fine;

```
       var queryx = (from sa in d1.SampleAttributes
                      where nodeTable.ToList().Distinct().Contains(sa.client_post_code_prefix)
                     select sa.SampleId).Distinct();
```

Note: nodeTable is of type IQueryable

However, I would like to change this so that the column name within the contain method can be decided at runtime. I determine the column name from another query dependent on certain user filters being applied and would ideally like something with the follwing logic;

//please note that the string I pass into obtain a 'column object' always shares the same name as the column

```
        var columnWhatever = GetColumnName(string colName);

        var queryx = (from sa in d1.SampleAttributes
                      where nodeTable.ToList().Distinct().Contains(sa.client_post_code_prefix)
                     select sa.SampleId).Distinct();
```

So far I have been unable to find anything that will allow this and I'm beggining to think that Linq does not allow such logic. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148309/how-do-i-reference-a-field-in-linq-based-on-a-dynamic-fieldname

Comment: @Rob - not necessarily; the first could be answered with reflection, but this may be something else...

Comment: @saj - what is the underlying LINQ implementation here? LINQ-to-Objects? Entity Framework? LINQ-to-SQL? It matters, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the type of `nodeTable`? Is this LINQ to SQL or LINQ to objects?

Comment: By the way, your `where` clause should be `nodeTable.Contains(sa.client_post_code_prefix)`.  
There's no point in calling `ToList().Distinct()`; it'll just waste time and memory.

Comment: thanks for the heads up SLaks, I think I started like you suggest but after trying all sorts ended up with what I put up

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at the Dynamic LINQ library.  I posted about it [here](http://www.sullivansoftdev.com/blog/2009/09/19/getting-around-some-anonymous-type-headaches-with-dynamic-linq/).  Take a look and see if that might help you.  Also see Scott Guthrie's post about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: By far the worst of both worlds: dynamic sql and linq.  great.

Answer (score 2):

If this is LINQ to object you can do this very easily using reflection. To wit:

```
string colName;
var queryx = (from sa in d1.SampleAttributes
              where nodeTable.Contains(
                                 sa.GetType()
                                   .GetProperty(colName)
                                   .GetValue(sa, null)
                                   .ToString()
                             )
              select sa.SampleId).Distinct();
```

This is assuming that `nodeTable` is an `IEnumerable<string>`.

It would be better to only perform the reflection piece once. Say that the compile-time type of `sa` is `SampleAttribute`. Then you could do the following:

```
string colName;
PropertyInfo info = typeof(SampleAttribute).GetProperty(colName);
Func<SampleAttribute, string> func = sa => info.GetValue(sa, null).ToString();
var queryx = (from sa in d1.SampleAttributes
              where nodeTable.Contains(func(sa))
              select sa.SampleId).Distinct();
```

If this is LINQ to SQL you can do this easily using [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx). If you give a little more detail about the type of `nodeTable` I can walk you through this.

Comment: Hi Jason this is linq to sql. I'm assuming your answer would not apply to linq to sql although on first sight I can't understand why it would work on linq to object and not on linq to sql.

Comment: And nodeTable is of type IQueryable<string>. Thanks