# Generic repository implementation with EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, repository, repository-pattern

For a simple repository

```
public interface ISimpleRepository<T>
{
    IApplicationState AppState { get; set; }
    void Add(T instance);
    void Delete(T instance);
    void Delete(Guid rowGuid);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T Load(Guid rowGuid);
    void SaveChanges();
    void Update(T instance);
}
```

my implementation of the `Load()` method for specific repository for class `Product` might look like this:

```
    public Product Load(Guid rowid)
    {
        return (from c in _ctx.Products where c.id == rowid select c).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Now this is assumed when my repository implementation class looks like this:

```
public class EntityFrameworkProductsProvider : IRepository<Product> ...
```

What if I had like dozens or hundreds of this small and simple entities that would all use the same behaviour when doing CRUDs (use the same implementation of methods)? I certainly don't want to go and create a class to implement IRepository for each one of them..

I want something like this:

```
public class EntityFrameworkDefaultProvider<T> : IRepository<T> ...
```

but I don't know how to implement the LINQ Select expression then because of course I can't write `from e in _ctx.T where e...` or do I?

I haven't run into this scenario yet because so far I only had very specific entities with custom repository implementation.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://bit.ly/gAoDnO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing `_ctx.Products`, you can write `_ctx.Set<T>`. That takes care of half of the problem (you need to add a generic constraint `where T: class` to your repository)

Then, if rowid is the object's key, you can use `_ctx.Set<T>.Find(rowid)` instead of a LINQ query to retrieve by Id.

Alternatively, you can create a base interface `IHaveId` (or a `BaseEntity` class, whatever you like) which has the `Id` property, and then add that as an generic constraint on T, so you can use it in your queries.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: What if the id contains more then 1 column?

Comment: @Naor: they don't according to his interface. It's a bad practice anyway, but `Find` supports passing an `object[]` (as `params`), so he could theoretically add that too.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: But how the Find method knows how to map each object to each key? I asked Ladislav Mrnka also in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166297/generic-repository-ef4-ctp5-getbyid/5167709#5167709.

Comment: @Naor: By the order in which they are defined using the `HasKey` method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671266(v=VS.103).aspx

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon: And where does the HashKey defined?

Comment: @Naor: I have just sent you the link. It's all in the docs. And blog posts by the ADO.NET team.

Answer (score 4):

Because you tagged your question with [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) and [entity-framework-4](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-4) I assume you are using ObjectContext API. `ObjectContext` offers method `CreateObjectSet<T>` which is equivalent of `Set<T>` on `DbContext`.

This question is actually duplicate of either:

- [Generic GetById with DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166297/generic-repository-ef4-ctp5-getbyid)
- [Generic GetById with ObjectContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273416/entity-framework-simple-generic-getbyid-but-has-differents-pk-name)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using EF 4.1, see the sample generic repository here:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is possible in EF4.1 with the DbContext API, where you have a "Set" method on the context that gets you the entity set corresponding to the type T. this way, you could have your repository like this:

```
public class EntityFrameworkDefaultProvider<T> : IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    public T Load(Guid rowId)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(rowId);
    }
}
```

one more remark: I think you could use this syntax :

```
return _ctx.Products.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.id == rowid);
```

to get the entity you want instead of using the (from... in...). it's clearer (in my opinion)  :)

Hope this helps