# generic GetById for complex PK

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am looking a way to create Generic GetById that get `params object[]` as parameter, knows to find the key/s field/s and know to find the relevant entity.

In the way to find a solution I thought on a generic method that returns the PK fields definition and a generic method that can return the entity based on fields.

I am looking for something I can use in table with one or more fields as primary key.

**EDIT**
one or more fields as primary key example =
table Customers have (CompanyId, CustomerName, Address, CreateDate).
The primary key of Customers are CompanyId are CustomerName.

I am looking for generic GetById that will know to handle also those such of tables.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do? How can you have “one or more fields as primary key”? Do you mean composite key?

Comment: conceptually, would this be simiar to what a compiler needs to do when it chooses the correct overload?

Answer (score 4):

You can't get "generic" approach if you don't know how many members is in the key and what types do they have. I modified [my solution for single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273416/entity-framework-simple-generic-getbyid-but-has-differents-pk-name/5278684#5278684) to multiple keys but as you can see it is not generic - it uses order in which keys are defined:

```
// Base repository class for entity with any complex key
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly string _entitySetName;
    private readonly string[] _keyNames;

    protected ObjectContext Context { get; private set; }
    protected ObjectSet<TEntity> ObjectSet { get; private set; }

    protected RepositoryBase(ObjectContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        Context = context;
        ObjectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();

        // Get entity set for current entity type
        var entitySet = ObjectSet.EntitySet;
        // Build full name of entity set for current entity type
        _entitySetName = context.DefaultContainerName + "." + entitySet.Name;
        // Get name of the entity's key properties
        _keyNames = entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name).ToArray();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByKey(params object[] keys)
    {
        if (keys.Length != _keyNames.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of key members");
        }

        // Merge key names and values by its order in array
        var keyPairs = _keyNames.Zip(keys, (keyName, keyValue) => 
            new KeyValuePair<string, object>(keyName, keyValue));

        // Build entity key
        var entityKey = new EntityKey(_entitySetName, keyPairs);
        // Query first current state manager and if entity is not found query database!!!
        return (TEntity)Context.GetObjectByKey(entityKey);
    }

    // Rest of repository implementation
}
```

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Why did you mark the repository as abstract?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: What is the difference between your solution here and your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166297/generic-repository-ef4-ctp5-getbyid/5167709#5167709?

Comment: @Naor: The difference is between version of EF. This one is for ObjectContext API and EFv4 the linked one is for DbContext API and EFv4.1

Comment: @Naor: Why did I mark repository abstract? Because I don't believe in generic repository. The idea of generic respository works only in very simple scenarios.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Where can I find documents about the ObjectContext VS the DbContext? Until now I wan't realized there are two approaches. Does this meens that the ObjectContext will replaced by the DbContext?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: But Generic Repository gives you a lot! the basic methods - Insert, Update, Delete, Select are given you for free when creating a new entity. And those are very common operations and huge benefit. What do you think?

Comment: @Naor: DbContext API is simplified version mainly used for code-first but it works with EDMX as well. This is typical question for Google.

Comment: @Naor: That is the reason why I defined repository as abstract. Those common methods form base layer of concrete repository.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I am using IObjectSet<T> as object set and I don't have EntitySet property (ObjectSet.EntitySet fails).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how useful this would be because it is generic but you could do this:

```
public TEntity GetById<TEntity>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>[] keys) where TEntity : class
{
    if (keys == null)
      return default(TEntity);

    var table = context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = null;
    foreach (var item in keys)
    {
        if (query == null)
            query = table.Where(item);
        else
            query = query.Where(item);
    }
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and then you could call it like this:

```
var result = this.GetById<MyEntity>(a => a.EntityProperty1 == 2, a => a.EntityProperty2 == DateTime.Now);
```

Disclaimer: this really isn't a GetByid, it's really a "let me give you a couple parameters and give me the first entity that matches". But that being said, it uses generics and it will return an entity if there is a match and you search based on primary keys.

Comment: This is the same like doing where.

Comment: @Naor, not exactly, Where returns `IQueryable<TEntity>` this will return `TEntity`

Comment: So this is the same like Single.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't implement such thing because you won't be able to join between each passed value with the appropriate key field.

I'd suggest using custom method for each entity:

Assuming `Code` and `Name` are keys in `Person` table:

```
 public IEnumerable<Person> ReadById(int code, string name)
 {
     using (var entities = new Entities())
        return entities.Persons.Where(p => p.Code = code && p.Name = name);
 }
```

Comment: But this s what I want to avoid - writing each class GetById method.

Comment: @Napr: No generic way in my mind, but I think they'll not be too many.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my second stab at it. I think this would work for you.

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static Customer GetByKey(this IQueryable<Customer> query, int customerId,string customerName)
    {
        return query.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CustomerId == customerId && a.CustomerName == customerName);
    }

}
```

So the beauty behind this extension method is you can now do this:

```
Customer customer = Db.Customers.GetByKey(1,"myname");
```

You obviously have to do this for every type, but probably worth it if you need it :)

Comment: Jose, this is nice answer but I am looking for a generic way that will support more then one fields as primary key. In your version I have to write a method for each class and make this method generic will make problems with tables with more then one field as pk.

Answer (score 0):

I think the set up is a bit but I do think creating a reusable pattern will pay off in the long run. I just wrote this up and haven't tested, but I based off a searching pattern I use a lot.

Required Interfaces:

```
public interface IKeyContainer<T>
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetKey();
}

public interface IGetService<T>
{
    T GetByKey(IKeyContainer<T> key);
}
```

Example Entities:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexFoo
{
    public int Key1 { get; set; }

    public int Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation Example:

```
public class FooKeyContainer : IKeyContainer<Foo>
{
    private readonly int _id;

    public FooKeyContainer(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> GetKey()
    {
        Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> key = x => x.Id == _id;
        return key;
    }
}

public class ComplexFooKeyContainer : IKeyContainer<ComplexFoo>
{
    private readonly int _id;
    private readonly int _id2;

    public ComplexFooKeyContainer(int id, int id2)
    {
        _id = id;
        _id2 = id2;
    }

    public Expression<Func<ComplexFoo, bool>> GetKey()
    {
        Expression<Func<ComplexFoo, bool>> key = x => x.Key1 == _id && x.Key2 == _id2;
        return key;
    }
}

public class ComplexFooService : IGetService<ComplexFoo>
{
    public ComplexFoo GetByKey(IKeyContainer<ComplexFoo> key)
    {
       var entities = new List<ComplexFoo>();            
       return entities.Where(key.GetKey()).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var complexFoo = ComplexFooService.GetByKey(new ComplexFooKeyContainer(1, 2));
```