# Generic Find() with Includes Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I currently have a complete generic repository but I'm missing one feature and that is to use 
**Include()** and `Find()` together.

So now I have:

```
public E FindById<E>(int id) where E : class
{
    return DataContext.Set<E>().Find(id);
}
```

called using

```
var person = PersonRepo.FindById<Person>(personId);
```

I would like to have something similar to:

```
var person = PersonRepo.FindByIdWithIncludes<Person>(personId,new[]{"State.Address"});
```

So, something along this lines (this is only a test):

```
public E FindByIdWithIncludes<E>(int id, string[] includes) where E : class
{
    var entitySet = DataContext.Set<E>();
    DbQuery<E> entityQuery;

    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
        entityQuery = entitySet.Include(include);
    }

    return entityQuery.Find(id); //this is were it breaks
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use `Find` directly - `Find` doesn't work with includes. You must use `SingleOrDefault`.

First you need to define interface for your entities to expose their key.

```
public interface IEntityWithId 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Next you can write simple method with constrain to get access to the key:

```
public E FindByIdWithIncludes<E>(int id, string[] includes) 
    where E : class, IEntityWithId
{          

    IQueryable<E> entityQuery = DataContext.Set<E>();

    foreach (var include in includes)
    {
            entityQuery = entityQuery.Include(include);
    }

    return entityQuery.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id); 
}
```

Btw. you can use strongly typed includes - [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637).

Comment: I'm interested in how would you expose entity key if there are not named Id, rather [TableName]Id? I've already implemented the strongly typed includes as i found your post while researching for my problem. Regards

Comment: I have previously answered similar questions for ObjectContext - you will just need to convert DbContext to ObjectContext: check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273416/entity-framework-simple-generic-getbyid-but-has-differents-pk-name/5278684#5278684) and [more complex one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794902/generic-getbyid-for-complex-pk/5795480#5795480) but you will simply help yourselves a lot if you use the same key name and interface.

Comment: Thank you. I use the same key name but the DB i'm currently working on is messed up. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could go also the other way around, to use `Find`, but in combination with `Load`. In some cases might be better performing than `Include-SingleOrDefault`, but it really depends on the scenario.

Non-generic example:

```
 private User GetByUID(int uID, bool includeDetails = false, bool includeAddresses = false)
 {
    var result = context.Users.Find(uID);
    if (includeDetails)
    {
       // load user-details (1:1 relation)
       context.Entry(result)
              .Reference<UserDetails>(us => us.UserDetails)
              .Load();
    }
    if (includeAddresses) 
    {
       // load user-addresses (1:m relation)
       context.Entry(result)
              .Collection(us => us.Addresses)
              .Load();    
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Should not be difficult to make it generic to your needs.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this will cause multiple queries to be sent to the server. `Include` OTOH would allow fetching all the data with a simple query. So although this solution works, it's important to understand it may not always be a suitable replacement to `Include` extension.