# Entity Framework, LINQ and Generics

Tags: entity-framework, generics, ado.net, repository-pattern

I have the following code:

```
public interface IKeyed<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; }
}

// This is the entity framework generated model. I have added the
//    IKeyed<Guid> interface
public partial class Person : IKeyed<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<TKey, TEntity> : IKeyedRepository<TKey, TEntity>
               where TEntity : class, IKeyed<TKey>
{
    private readonly IObjectSet<TEntity> _objectSet;

    public Repository(IOjectSet<TEntity> objectSet)
    {
        _objectSet = objectSet;
    }

    public TEntity FindBy(TKey id)
    {
         return _objectSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }
}
```

[Update]
Here is how I am calling this:

```
Db2Entities context = new Db2Entities(_connectionString); // This is the EF context
IObjectSet<Person> objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<Person>();

IKeyedRepository<Guid, Person> repo = new Repository<Guid, Person>(objectSet);

Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
Person person = repo.FindBy(id);   // This throws the exception.
```

The above code compiles. When the 'FindBy' method is executed, I get the following error:

*Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types (for instance Int32, String and Guid) are supported in this context.*

Since the type of my 'Id' is a Guid (one of the primitive types supported) it seems like I should be able to massage this into working.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: If I have to judge by my adventures into writing linq providers to stuff, I assume EF's provider parses the expression given to first or default by type. And type of id is TKey which is NOT typeof(Guid).

Comment: I believe TDaver is right. The code actually works if you would have a non-generic parameter `Guid` instead the the generic `TKey` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work this way. You cannot call `Equals` because EF doesn't know how to translate it to SQL. When you pass expression to `FirstOrDefault` it must be always only code which can be translated to SQL. It is probably possible to solve your problem with some manual building of expression tree but I can reference other solutions already discussed on Stack Overflow.

`ObjectContext` offers method named `GetObjectByKey` which is exactly what you are trying to do. The problem is that it requires `EntityKey` as parameter. Here are two answers which show how to use this method and how to get `EntityKey`:

- [Entity Framework Simple Generic GetByID but has differents PK Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273416/entity-framework-simple-generic-getbyid-but-has-differents-pk-name/5278684#5278684)
- [generic GetById for complex PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794902/generic-getbyid-for-complex-pk)

In your case the code will be less complicated because you know the name of the key property so you generally need only something like this:

```
public virtual TEntity FindBy(TKey id)
{
    // Build entity key
    var entityKey = new EntityKey(_entitySetName, "Id", key);
    // Query first current state manager and if entity is not found query database!!!
    return (TEntity)Context.GetObjectByKey(entityKey);
}
```

The problem here is that you cannot get `entitySetName` from `IObjectSet` so you must either pass it to repository constructor or you must pass `ObjectSet`.

Just in case you will want to use DbContext API (EFv4.1) in the future instead of ObjectContext API it will be much simplified because `DbSet` offers `Find` method:

- [generic repository EF4 CTP5 getById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166297/generic-repository-ef4-ctp5-getbyid/5167709#5167709)

Comment: I believe `Equals` isn't the problem. Usually it is allowed in LTE and translates to SQL. I think the problem falls under the category of "referencing a non-scalar variable" in a LTE query (the generic TKey parameter) which causes the exception (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx)

Comment: I was able to implement using @Ladislav advice. If you are interested in seeing the final result it is here: https://github.com/rcravens/GenericRepository