# Is there a way to make a IEnumerable method that lets me return any list type in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

So currently, you can imagine I have 1 method that is the constructor that funcitons like

```
info.PersonalInfo=getPersonalInfo(Id);
info.MedicalInfo=getMedicalInfo(Id);
```

Thing is, all of those get data and get binarys are repeating 95% of the code

```
                using (CVDataEntities data = new CVDataEntities())
            {
                var temp = data.PersonalInfo.Where(m => m.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
                return temp;
            }
```

The only thing that changes is instead of PersonalInfo its MedicalInfo.
I thought of using a switch and just sending a number as the selector for which specific object I would want.

But the problem is the method is made so that it can only return

```
 public  IEnumerable<PersonalInfo> getPersonalInfo (string Id)
```

Is there any way for me to make a IEnumerable that lets me return any object, or is there a better way to go about this. I want to do it mostly to reduce the code from 400 lines down to 200 at most.

Comment: Are you asking how to make `getPersonalInfo` generic?

Comment: if you're using an entity framework DbContext, you can use the `.Set<TEntity>()` method to get the desired table. but your entities need a common base class/interface containing the `Id`-property.

Comment: Do you mean using [generic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods), making something like `public IEnumerable<T> getPersonalInfo<T>(string Id)` where T is the type you want to return?

Comment: yea, instead of making 100 different methods to go for each method

Comment: error brian is probably what im looking for thanks Ill go ahead and try it.

Comment: Seems duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156538/entityframework-get-object-by-id

Answer (score 0):

Try using [generic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods), you will be able to specify the return type of your function when you call it. This could make your code look like this :

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> getInfo<T>(string id)
{
    // Some code
}

// Calling the function
info.PersonalInfo = getInfo<PersonalInfo>(Id);
info.MedicalInfo = getInfo<MedicalInfo>(Id);
```

But be careful while using it, cause the compiler won't know what type `T` is (it is only defined at runtime) so it could lead to some errors while processing the data (like missing properties / methods exclusive to a specific type)

EDIT : Johnathan Barclay made a good point by commenting that the `// some code` bit is relevant and asked "How would the correct property be selected on `data`? How do you access an `Id` property on `T`?"

To get the correct property and access an `Id` property, you could use [System.Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) and add a string parameter to get the name of the property you want to use, and another to give the `Id` property name to the function:

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> getInfo<T>(string id, string propertyToReadName, string propertyToCompareName)
{
    using (CVDataEntities data = new CVDataEntities())
    {
        // Getting the enumerable not filtered first
        IEnumerable<T> unfilteredList = (IEnumerable<T>)data.GetType()                        // Get the type
                                                  .GetProperty(propertyToReadName, typeof(T)) // Get the property (PersonalInfo or MedicalInfo)
                                                  .GetValue(data);                            // Get the value of this property in the `data` instance

        // Filtering the list
        IEnumerable<T> filteredList = unfilteredList.Where(m =>
            typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyToCompareName) // Get the "id" property using parameter
                     .GetValue(m)                        // Get the "id" value of m instance
                     .Equals(id));                       // Check if it equals the id given as parameter

        return filteredList;
    }
}

// Calling the function
info.PersonalInfo = getInfo<PersonalInfo>(Id, "PersonalInfo", "Id");
info.MedicalInfo = getInfo<MedicalInfo>(Id, "MedicalInfo", "Id");
```

If you want to return a single element instead of an `IEnumerable` don't forget to change the return type of the function from `IEnumerable<T>` to `T` and add `.FirstOrDefault()` at the return line

Note that you could also give another value to the parameter `propertyToCompareName` and make a comparison to another property of the `T` class

Comment: The `// Some code` bit is relevant here. How would the correct property be selected on `data`? How do you access an `Id` property on `T`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay You're absolutely right, I updated my answer

Comment: Whilst this may work, reflection is sub-optimal here; there are statically-typed alternatives which should be preferred.

Comment: if `CVDataEntities` is a DbContext `data.Set<T>().Find(id)` will work without using reflection