# Can I write a generic repository with the db first scenario to dynamically get me an entity by id?

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'd like to know how to create a method that will allow me to generically do this...

```
public class Repo<T> : IGenericRepo<T> where T : class
    {
        protected PteDotNetEntities db;

        public T Get(int id)
        {
            //how do I dynamically get to the correct entity object and select it by
            //id?
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. If you know that all your entities will have simple primary key property of type `int` and name `Id` you can do simply this:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

All your entities must implement this interface. Next you can simply do:

```
public class Repo<T> : IGenericRepo<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected PteDotNetEntities db;

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return db.CreateObjectSet<T>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
```

This is the simplest possible solution. There are better solutions using `GetObjectByKey` but they are more complex. The difference between `FirstOrDefault` and `GetObjectByKey` is repeatable execution. `FirstOrDefault` always executes DB query whereas `GetObjectByKey` first checks if the entity with the same key was already loaded / attached to the context and returns it without querying the database. As reference for version using `GetObjectByKey` you can check similar questions:

- [Entity Framework Simple Generic GetByID but has differents PK Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273416/entity-framework-simple-generic-getbyid-but-has-differents-pk-name)
- [Generic GetById for complex PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794902/generic-getbyid-for-complex-pk)

You can simplify those examples if you know the name of the key property upfront (forced by the interface).

In case of using code first / DbContext API you can also check this question:

- [Generic repository EF4 CTP5 getById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166297/generic-repository-ef4-ctp5-getbyid)