# C# MVC generic repository class with interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, inheritance, repository

How can I achieve something like the following example?

```
public interface IGenericRepository {
   int id { get; }
   T GetById<T>() where T : class
}

public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository {
   //Some code here

   public T GetById<T>(int tid) where T : class
   {
       return from tbl in dataContext.GetTable<T> where tbl.id == tid select tbl;
   }
}
```

and I would like to use this as follows:

```
GenericRepository gr = new GenericRepository();
Category cat = gr.GetById<Category>(15);
```

Of course this code does not work since if I define `T : class` then the `tbl.id` part won't work. But of course, there should be a way to realize this.

**UPDATE**

Considering driis' answer, I am doing the following, but I still can't get this working:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int id { get; }
}

public interface IGenericRepository : IEntity
{
    T GetById<T>(int id);
}

public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository
{
    public T GetById<T>(int id) {
    return from tbl in dataContext.GetTable<T> where tbl.id == tid select tbl;
    }
}
```

At this point `tbl.id` works, but `dataContext.GetTable<T>` is giving me a error.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735140/c-linq-to-sql-refectoring-this-generic-getbyid-method

Answer (score 5):

You can *constrain* T to be a type that contains an ID, you will likely want an interface for it:

```
public interface IEntity 
{ 
    int Id { get; }
}
```

Then declare your generic method as:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetById<T>(int tid) where T : IEntity
{ 
   return from tbl in dataContext.GetTable<T> where tbl.id == tid select tbl;
}
```

Of course you will need to implement IEntity for all entities. I am guessing you are using Linq2Sql or similar, in which case you can just make a partial class definition that includes the interface implementation.

Comment: and in which interface should I define T GetByID<T>(int tid) ? or even a better question: do I need to define it within an interface? :D

Comment: You are likely to want GetById<T> to be in your base repository interface.

Comment: I am sorry but I am really new at this stuff, can you please provide a full example? Because when I try to implement IEntity GetTable<T> does not work since it requires a reference type.

Comment: IEntity should not have a GetTable method. It should be in IGenericRepository and implemented in GenericRepository, following your model. Remember to pay attention to the generic constraint (the `where :` part, it needs to be the same in the interface and implementation.

Comment: please see my update and help me from there, I'm struggling with this issue for more than 3 hours so there's left a lil for me to go crazy. @driis