# Why i can't make this generic repository to work ? What wrong?

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, repository

I have this generic repository.

```
 /// <summary>
/// Implémentation de base d'un dépositoire pour Entity Framework.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Entity Framework 4.1</remarks>
/// <typeparam name="TEntite">Entité spécifique.</typeparam>
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TKey>
    where TKey : class
{
    private readonly IContext _context;
    private ObjectContext _objectContext;
    private IObjectSet<TEntity> _objectSet;

    protected RepositoryBase(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _objectContext = _context.GetObjectContext();
        _objectSet = _objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    }

    /// <see cref="IRepository.cs"/>
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> sortExpression)
    {
        if (sortExpression == null)
            sortExpression = x => x.Id;
        return _objectSet.OrderBy(sortExpression).AsEnumerable();
    }

    /// <see cref="IRepository.cs"/>
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(int maximumRows, int startRowIndex, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> sortExpression)
    {
        if (sortExpression == null)
            sortExpression = x => x.Id;
        return _objectSet.OrderBy(sortExpression).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows).AsEnumerable();
    }

    /// <see cref="IRepository.cs"/>
    public TEntity SelectByKey(TKey key) 
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("La clé était NULL! Une clé est nécessaire pour récupérer un entité.");
        return _objectSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == key);
    }
```

Here the specific implementation...

> ```
> public class ProductRepository : RepositoryBase<Product, int>, IProductRepository
> {
>     public ProductRepository(IContext context)
>         : base(context)
>     { }
> ```

```
    /// <see cref="IProductRepository.cs"/>
    public Product GetByName(string name)
    {
        return base.First(x => x.Name == name);
    }

    /// <see cref="IProductRepository.cs"/>
    public IEnumerable<Product> FindProduct(Specification<Product> specification)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When i create a specific repository.. it say that Tkey must be a reference type but why ? Is there a way to make this generic repository work ? TKey was used in order to make the method SelectByKey accept a key type.

**Edit #1:**

If i remove the constrain then i have another problem... TKey cannot be compared with TKey using == as lambda expression in my SelectByKey method.

**Edit #2:**

Tried to use Equals and the syntax seem to be ok.

**Edit #3:**

Equals crash at runtime.. saying Tkey (which seem to be a System.Object) can't use equals which doesnt seem logic since object have the equal method. I currently doesn't have access to the real code but i did some test with this code below..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test<TestEntity, int> t = new Test<TestEntity, int>();  
        t.TestMethod(5);
    }
}

class Test<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : Entity<TKey>
{
    public Test()
    { }

    public TestEntity TestMethod(TKey id)
    {
        List<TestEntity> testEntity = new List<TestEntity>();
        testEntity.Add(new TestEntity(5));
        return testEntity.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }
}

class Entity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
}

class TestEntity : Entity
{
    public TestEntity(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

class Entity : Entity<int>
{
}
```

And it seem to work pretty well. So i will try later tonight.

**Edit #4**

Alright the exception i get is Canoot create a constant value of type "System.Object". Only primary types such int32, string and guid are supported by this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your repository declaration

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TKey>
    where TKey : class
{
```

you have specified the class constraint which will only allows reference types. See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> where T : class
>
> The type argument must be a reference type, including any class,
>   interface, delegate, or array type. (See note below.)

Remove the : class constraint to allow any type.

Unless you're engaged in a learning exercise, I would not try to build your repository from scratch. I would leverage off what others have done. When I wrote a repository framework, I wanted a GetById method that would work with primary keys of varying types (although not multiple column primary keys). When writing it, I found the following two posts especially helpful:

[C# LINQ to SQL: Refactoring this Generic GetByID method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735140/c-linq-to-sql-refectoring-this-generic-getbyid-method)

http://goneale.com/2009/07/27/linq-to-sql-generic-repository/

Comment: Fixed the problem by using Equals instead. Thanks!

Comment: umm nope doesnt work. so instead i removed the SelectByKey method.. unfortunally.

Comment: @Rushino why didn't Equals work? It seems like it should have.

Comment: @Rushino - how does it not work - what error do you get? Is it a compile time or run time error?

Comment: @hatchet I get a runtime error. TKey seem to be considered as a System.Object which i try to compare with an integer. Umm.

Comment: @phoog As said to hatchet i get a runtime error.. but i will wait toning to see exactly which error i am getting and i will get back to you guys. Cause i tried it as stated in Edit 3 of my post in an isolated exemple and it seem to work so i might have forgot something. What is strange is that it act like if it was an object.

Comment: What i said make a bit non sence "What is strange is that it act like if it was an object." what i meant is that id seemed to be an object at runtime and not an int as it was supposed to be.

Comment: @Rushino - I'm a little lost as to which of the code you've posted is throwing that, but my best advice is to look at the two links I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> it say that Tkey must be a reference type but why ?

You have the constraint:

> `where TKey : class`

Do you need the constraint? What key types do you want to support?

Comment: Every possible types.. i mean int, string, etc. All those type.

Comment: In that case I'd remove the constraint.  An int key won't satisfy the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
```

Should fix the problem and allow you to use Equals syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at guid or int metadata by using f12 key, you'll se that it implement:

```
public struct int: IFormatable, IComparable, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<int> 
public struct Guid: IFormatable, IComparable, IComparable<Guid>, IEquatable<Guid>
```

then the constraint will be :

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TKey> 
  where TEntity: class, IEntity<TKey>
  where TKey: struct, IFormatable, IComparable, IComparable<TKey>, IEquatable<TKey>
```

and IEntity interface must be like this:

```
public interface IEntity<TKey> where TKey: struct, IFormatable, 
                               IComparable, IComparable<TKey>, IEquatable<TKey>
```

but the operator == still not working for me, but the Equals method works as we expect, still searching for a solution for the equality operator.