# Linq Select by PK?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, attributes

Is it possible to perform a LinQ select by PK dynamically ?

Something like that :

```
public T FindByPK(IEnumerable<T> table, T itemToFind)
{

}
```

T is a mapping from table (LinQ to SQL autogenerated).

I tryed using reflection but I don't know how to get the attribute "IsPrimaryKey" and then perform the LinQ because sometimes the PK contains more than one column.

**EDIT after Answer by chridam**

So, I can now do a GetByPK but it assumes that the PK is only one column...

```
public static class DataContextHelpers
{
    public static T GetByPk<T>(this DataContext context, object pk) where T : class {
        var table = context.GetTable<T>();
        var mapping = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));
        var pkfield = mapping.RowType.DataMembers.SingleOrDefault(d => d.IsPrimaryKey);
        if (pkfield == null)
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Table {0} does not contain a Primary Key field", mapping.TableName));
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, pkfield.Name), Expression.Constant(pk)), param);
        return table.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

I changed the code like this to be able to get all columns of the primary keys and also, the object pk has to be a row of the table (because I don't know what are the pk columns)

```
public static T GetByPk<T>(this DataContext context, T row) where T : class
        {
            var table = context.GetTable<T>();
            var mapping = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));

            var pkfield = mapping.RowType.DataMembers.Where(d => d.IsPrimaryKey);
            if (!pkfield.Any())
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Table {0} does not contain a Primary Key field", mapping.TableName));
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, pkfield??), Expression.Property(param, row??)), param);
            return table.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
        }
```

So, I am stuck at Expression.Property who need only one property and not a group of many.

Comment: are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: No, I just use a dbml file ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try writing an extension method onto your `DataContext` object that facilitates the pulling of records from the database by their Primary Key, as outlined by Chris Sainty in his blog post [LINQ to SQL: Generic Primary Key function](http://blog.csainty.com/2008/04/linq-to-sql-generic-primary-key.html) :

```
public static class DataContextHelpers
{
    public static T GetByPk<T>(this DataContext context, object pk) where T : class {
        var table = context.GetTable<T>();
        var mapping = context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T));
        var pkfield = mapping.RowType.DataMembers.SingleOrDefault(d => d.IsPrimaryKey);
        if (pkfield == null)
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Table {0} does not contain a Primary Key field", mapping.TableName));
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, pkfield.Name), Expression.Constant(pk)), param);
        return table.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

Then call the method by way of:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
Product p = db.GetByPk<Product>(1);
```

You might also want to have a look at Denis Troller's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735888/122005) as an alternative.

Comment: Let's try this because Denis Troller's answer is from PK with only one column ^^

Comment: Your example is also for only one column as PK and I found a lot of examples like this but didn't find for when the PK contains more than one column =)

Comment: You could modify the mapping object `pkfield`, instead of it returning `SingleOrDefault`, you could just return `mapping.RowType.DataMembers.Any(d => d.IsPrimaryKey)`;

Comment: Yes, that's what I did (`mapping.RowType.DataMembers.Where` then `if (pkfield.Any())` but then, I can't do `Expression.Property(param, pkfield.Name)` because it become a collection :)

Comment: You're almost there, I think. Trying to figure out also how we can change the predicate object to map multiple columns :S

Comment: I think that it's harder than I figured because it look like all examples found on internet are presuming that primary key contain only one column.

Comment: That could be a breakthrough if a solution was found. Let me get on this should time permits and let me know if you find any success but I think you should be in the right frame.

Comment: Ok, i did it !
I am going to look if I can do better and then post my solution here.